# How do I convert from a long to an Access Date/Time value in Jackcess?

Tags: ms-access, java-7, jackcess

I have the following code:

```
// Model the table
  Table tbl = new TableBuilder("Transactions")
    .addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("TransactionID", DataType.LONG).setAutoNumber(true))
    .addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("ControllerID", DataType.LONG).setAutoNumber(false))
    .addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("ReaderID", DataType.LONG).setAutoNumber(false))
    .addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("Event", DataType.LONG).setAutoNumber(false))
    .addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("Timestamp", DataType.SHORT_DATE_TIME).setAutoNumber(false))
    .addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("Number", DataType.LONG).setAutoNumber(false))
    .addIndex(new IndexBuilder(IndexBuilder.PRIMARY_KEY_NAME).addColumns("TransactionID").setPrimaryKey())
    .toTable(db);
  // Add the row
  Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
  values.put("ControllerID", cid);
  values.put("ReaderID", rid);
  values.put("Event", evtNum);
  values.put("Timestamp", ts); // Long; must be converted to DataType.SHORT_DATE_TIME
  values.put("Number", accNum);
  tbl.addRowFromMap(values);
```

I want to convert from a long, `ts` to a date format **that MS Access understands**. The type of the "Timestamp" column in MS Access is `Date/Time`, with values displayed in the form "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss". What do I need to do to convert `ts`?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3176188/2225787) to a similar problem makes mention of conversion to a `double` (which is what Access uses to store `Date/Time` fields, according to the source), but I don't understand what I need to do to my code to conform to it:

> This also points up the issue of the independence of display format and data storage with Jet/ACE date values. The storage is as a double, with the integer part indicating the day since 12/30/1899 and the decimal part the time portion within the day. Any date you enter is going to be stored as only one number.

— [David W. Fenton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9787/david-w-fenton); 4 July 2010

*Note:* I know [how to convert a long to a `java.util.Date`, set the time for a `java.util.Calendar`, then get a human-readable/parsable formatted String from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487460/converting-long-to-date-in-java-returns-1970). That's not what I'm trying to do, which is why marking as a duplicate of the linked question is incorrect. What I'm trying to do is get the double value that MS Access understands.

Comment: Have you tried:

Format ([FieldName], "mm/dd/yy") or the CDate function?For CDate, just do CDate(YourLongInt)

Comment: @DanielG From which _Java_ class(es)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is true that Access stores Date/Time values as `Double` floating-point numbers, you don't need to do that conversion yourself; Jackcess will do it for you. Just pass a `java.util.Date` to Jackcess and it will take care of the rest.

If your long `ts` is the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) then that could be as simple as

```
values.put("Timestamp", new java.util.Date(ts));
```

although Access doesn't really support fractional seconds, so it would be a bit safer to truncate the milliseconds by doing

```
values.put("Timestamp", new java.util.Date(ts / 1000 * 1000));
```

Note that such a conversion will use the current time zone of the Java Virtual Machine (JVM).